# Gluegen 32bit vs 64bit libraries

Tags: java, architecture, operating-system, jogl

I've got a Java application that uses Gluegen (and JOGL) to visualise some data in a 3D graph, my question comes down to the fact that if a user is running my application on a 32bit JRE on a 64bit machine, I'm not sure which version of the gluegen/jogl dll files I need to use.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 32-bit application needs a 32-bit DLL, regardless of where it is run. You should be able to code it so the application will look for the 32-bit library and if this fails the 64-bit library. i.e. whatever works ;)

Even better, you can use the bit-ness of the JRE to tell you which should work.

```
String bitness = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
```